# Could not redo log record on mirror

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transaction-log, mirroring

One of my database mirrors is in the suspended state today and the error log on the mirror shows the following.

> Could not redo log record (338934:102862:477), for transaction ID
>   (0:848150408), on page (1:3486737), database 'MyDB' (database ID 5).
>   Page: LSN = (338520:235006:14), type = 2. Log: OpCode = 11, context 3,
>   PrevPageLSN: (338520:235021:28). Restore from a backup of the
>   database, or repair the database.

Scary stuff.  However this isn't the first time it has happened and I have checked and double-checked and this isn't because of a normal physical change on the principal that couldn't be applied to the mirror such as a file getting added.  `DBCC CHECKDB` comes back clean.

I tried scanning the transaction log for the LSN given and found the following.

```
SELECT * FROM fn_dblog('338934:102862:477', '338934:102862:477')

Current LSN             Operation           Context         Transaction ID
00052bf6:000191ce:01dd  LOP_DELETE_SPLIT    LCX_INDEX_LEAF  0000:328dbf88

Description
Moved 176 row(s) at slot 0 from page 0001:00353411 to page 0000:00000000
```

I removed a lot of the columns in the output as they were null or didn't seem to have relevant information.

Why would a regular page split not be able to be restored?  I have also tried manually restoring the transaction logs and gotten the same error "could not redo log record.." error.

Any ideas what is going on?